# How to quick update MySQL table through a loop using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

My code for updating mysql table having  more than 2000 rows through a loop using VB.net is working fine but too slow. Is there any way to update it faster ? Anybody please help. Thanks. My code is given below.

```
Dim mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
    mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=1234;database=Share"
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM name_list;", mysqlconn)
    Dim datatable As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(datatable)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    cmd.Connection = mysqlconn
    Dim sql As String
    Dim i as integer = 0

    While i <= datatable.Rows.Count - 1

        Dim sy As String = datatable.Rows(i).Item(3).ToString.Trim

        sql = "UPDATE Name_list Set Numerology = '" & "N-" & variable1 & " S- " & variable2 & "',FSTLetter = '" & variable3 & "',Timing = '" & vriable4 & "',P_Numerology = '" & variable5 & "' WHERE Symbol = '" & sy & "'"
        sy = ""
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        i = i + 1

    End While

    adapter.Fill(datatable)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = datatable
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

Comment: Not an answer, but look into the topics of `Using` and parameterized queries

Answer (score 0):

Don't name variables the same as class names (`DataTable`, `datatable`) vb.net is case insensitive so it confuses intellisense.

Database connections and commands need to closed and disposed. 
`Using` blocks do this for you even if there is an error.

You can set the connection string by passing it directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise, you can set the command text and the connection by passing to the constructor of the command.

Don't open the connection until right before it is used. In this case we don't need a `DataAdapter` but if you are using one it is not necessary to open the connection at all. The `.Fill` method of the `DataAdapter` will open and close the connection. However if the `DataAdapter` finds an open connection it will leave it open.

To avoid confusion, I created 2 data tables. I used a single connection but I opened and closed it each time it is used. It is not disposed until the last `End Using`.

The first command retrieves only the sy column. Replace `Column4_Name` with the actual column name. We don't want to pull down data we don't need so no `Select *`.

Always use parameters to avoid sql injection which can damage your database. You need to check your database for the types of the fields. I had to guess. Each parameters value is set except sy which changes on each iteration.

No need to close the connection after the last Select command since the final End Using will close and dispose.

After the connection is closed we update the user interface.

```
Private Sub OPCode(variable1 As String, variable2 As String, variable3 As String, variable4 As String, variable5 As String)
    Dim dtBeforeUpdate As New DataTable()
    Dim dtAfterUpdate As New DataTable()
    Using mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=1234;database=Share")
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT Column4_Name FROM name_list;", mysqlconn)
            mysqlconn.Open()
            dtBeforeUpdate.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
            mysqlconn.Close()
        End Using
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand($"UPDATE Name_list Set Numerology = @Numerologh, FSTLetter = @FST, Timing = @Timing, P_Numerology = @P_Numerology WHERE Symbol =  @sy ", mysqlconn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Numerology", MySqlDbType.String).Value = $"N-{variable1} S- {variable2}"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FST", MySqlDbType.String).Value = variable3
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Timing", MySqlDbType.String).Value = variable4
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@P_Numerology", MySqlDbType.String).Value = variable5
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@sy", MySqlDbType.String)
            mysqlconn.Open()
            For Each row As DataRow In dtBeforeUpdate.Rows
                cmd.Parameters("@sy").Value = row(0).ToString.Trim
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            mysqlconn.Close()
        End Using
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * From Name_list;", mysqlconn)
            mysqlconn.Open()
            dtAfterUpdate.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtAfterUpdate
End Sub
```

Actually, I don't get it. It seems like you are updated the entire table with the same data. Do you expect the variable1, variable2 etc. to change somehow?

Answer (score -1):

Don't know where your variable1, variable2, etc come from, but those look to be static, so your loop is somewhat pointless it would seem. You're updating every row in the loop to the exact same values (unless there's other code you're not showing), so just update the table without the loop:

`Using con As New MySQLConnection
  con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=1234;database=Share"
  con.Open
  Using cmd As New MySQLCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Name_list Set Numerology = '" & "N-" & variable1 & " S- " & variable2 & "',FSTLetter = '" & variable3 & "',Timing = '" & vriable4 & "',P_Numerology = '" & variable5 & "'" 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
  End Using
End Using`

Comment: Respected sir, the variables come from the separate functions. To avoid posting large code I am not showing that functions. Thanks.

Comment: Understood. Did my suggestion make sense, or was there something I didn't understand about your question?

Comment: Respected Sir, would you please provide me the code to fast update through loop ? Because I am not enough experienced in VB.net. Thanks.

Comment: @ScottMcDaniel Always use parameters. Also, you forgot the Where clause.